# Excel Mac's start-up behavior changes when add-in's Auto_Open has MsgBox

Tags: macos, excel, vba

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011 (version 14.5.9) on OS X Yosemite (10.10.5).  If I
start Excel from the Dock, it pops up the "Excel Workbook Gallery" dialog.  If I start Excel by double-clicking an existing workbook in Finder, Excel opens the workbook as expected.

But these behaviors change if I install a simple add-in called "hello_world.xlam".  The add-in has just one standard VBA module ("Module1") with only this macro:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

The message box is displayed regardless of how Excel is started.  However, Excel seems to forget its default start-up behavior.  If I start Excel from the Dock, the "Excel Workbook Gallery" dialog is not displayed.  That's a minor issue.  The bigger issue is that if I start Excel by double-clicking a workbook in Finder, Excel does not open the workbook after the message box is closed.

If I disable this add-in (by going into Tools --> Adds-Ins, and unchecking the add-in), then the usual start-up behavior is restored.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered a work-around using an event procedure.  Deleted the Module1 from the hello_world add-in.  Added this procedure to the add-in's ThisWorkbook code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

The message box appears when Excel starts, and its start-up behavior remains unchanged.